# Elastic Search only matches full field

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search

I have just started using Elastic Search 6 on AWS.

I have inserted data into my ES endpoint but I can only search it using the full sentence and not match individual words. In the past I would have used not_analyzed it seems, but this has been replaced by 'keyword'. However this still doesn't work.

Here is my index:

```
{
  "seven" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "myobjects" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "myId" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "myUrl" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "myName" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "myText" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "seven",
        "creation_date" : "1519389595593",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "nGram_filter" : {
              "token_chars" : [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
              ],
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "type" : "nGram",
              "max_gram" : "20"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "nGram_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "nGram_filter"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "_vNXSADUTUaspBUu6zdh-g",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6000199"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have data like this:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 13,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "seven",
        "_type" : "myobjects",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "myUrl" : "https://myobjects.com/wales.gif",
          "myText" : "Objects for Welsh Things",
          "myName" : "Wales"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "seven",
        "_type" : "myobjects",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "myUrl" : "https://myobjects.com/flowers.gif",
          "myText" : "Objects for Flowery Things",
          "myNoun" : "Flowers"
        }
      }
     ]
  }
}
```

If I then search for 'Objects' I get nothing. If I search for 'Objects for Flowery Things' I get the single result.

I am using this to search for items :
POST /seven/objects/_search?pretty

```
{
    "query": {
            "multi_match" : { "query" : q, "fields": ["myText", "myNoun"], "fuzziness":"AUTO" }  
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me how to have the search match any word in the sentence rather than having to put the whole sentence in the query?

Comment: You have to read better the difference between keyword and text datatype. This behaviour is correct

Comment: I think you got that mixed up. To search without having to input the full sentence/text, you should NOT use not_analyzed / keyword.

In this case, change keyword to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `myName` and `myText` fields are of [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/keyword.html) type:

```
...
"myName" : {
  "type" : "keyword"
},
"myText" : {
  "type" : "keyword"
}
...
```

and because of this they are not analyzed and only full match will work for them. Change the type to `text` and it should work as you expected:

```
...
"myName" : {
  "type" : "text"
},
"myText" : {
  "type" : "text"
}
...
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Do I need to create a new index or can I alter the existing one?

Comment: I think the shorter option would be to create index again and index documents once again. You can also alter existing mapping but you probably will need to index existing document again as the changes will apply only for the new one. So the effect would be similar.